# Brownian motion and sup of a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, supremum-and-infimum

I am stuck with the following problem: let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $S_{t}:=\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s$. Prove that for every $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\mu \leq \lambda$, $\mathbb{P}(B_t \leq \mu, S_t \geq \lambda)=\mathbb{P}(B_t \geq 2 \lambda-\mu)$.

I know that for any $a>0,\ \mathbb{P}(S_t \geq a)=2 \mathbb{P}(B_t \geq a)$ but I do not know how I can use this fact.

Thank you very much !!

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_%28Wiener_process%29. Apply it here using the stopping time $\tau:=\inf\{s: B_s=\mu\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I solved it using, as a stopping time, $\tau:=\inf \left\{s : B_s=\lambda\right\}$